# How to do if I put a wrong field go to the field (anchor type)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I need help, I have a long form. And wanted when the client clicks on the submit it shows the field that was not filled.

Template :

```
    <div class="container"  [formGroup]="ClientForm">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-success':ClientForm.controls.input1.valid,'has-danger':!ClientForm.controls.input1.valid}">
    <label>Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 1" readonly formControlName="input1">
    <small class="form-text text-muted" [hidden]="ClientForm.controls.input1.valid">This field is required!</small>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(ClientForm)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>    Status: {{ClientForm.status}}
  </div>
```

Component:

```
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder){}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.bluidForm();
   }

   bluidForm(): void {
     this.ClientForm = this.fb.group({
       input1 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input2 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input3 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input4 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input5 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input6 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input7 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input8 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       input9 : new FormControl(null,Validators.required)
     })
   }
   onSubmit(dataRecibe){
     console.log(dataRecibe)
   }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/x5q7sVucARspL8bIITdQ?p=preview

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fast solution, just add `required` in your fields like so:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 2" formControlName="input2" required>
```

The message will be shown in browser, starting from the first empty field.

Was this the kind of solution you were looking for?

Your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cW7Gyt1J0YTK4ehGvPeI?p=preview)